# Spring Data Neo4j example -- how to adopt it to Spring Data Neo4j v4.1

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I am struggling how to convert this example: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-neo4j/ to work on new version of Spring Data. I obviously change imports for Person.java to org.neo4j.ogm.*. I have added:

```
  @Bean 
  public SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
  {
    logger.info("ApplicationConfig::getSessionFactory()");
    return new SessionFactory("hello");
  }

  @Bean
  public Session getSession() throws Exception {
    logger.info("Initialising Neo4jSession");
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = getSessionFactory();
        Assert.notNull(sessionFactory, "You must provide a SessionFactory instance in your Spring configuration classes");
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
  }
```

to Application.java file.
But I don't know how to change method:

> @Bean   CommandLineRunner   demo(PersonRepository personRepository,
>              GraphDatabase graphDatabase)

to work. I have tried move code from this method to constructor of its class, but I need to have PersonRepository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GraphDatabaseService should not be used to manage the transaction, if instead you inject a `org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session`, you will use
`session.beginTransaction()`

AFAIK, the PersonRepository will be injected as it was in SDN 3.

Here are two more articles introducing SDN 4.1-

http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2015/12/15/the-essence-of-spring-data-neo4j-4.html
http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2016/02/24/upgrading-spring-data-neo4j-4-1.html

Comment: Thanks. I haven't found and read this article before. It was helpful.